# IOS gives unexpected value for width on IOS7 and IOS8 version

Tags: ios, uiview, frame, bounds, autolayout

Hi I am developing IOS application. In my application I am checking for height width X and Y values of my view. In IB I am using auto layout with right left top and height constraints.I am not specifying width constraints.Inside viewDidLoad I am checking values for width height X and Y. For width value it gives unexpected value on IOS8 but on IOS7 it is giving proper value. for IOS7 it gives me width 320 which is expected and for IOS8 it is giving 600 which is not expected.

```
NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f ", _sampleView.frame.size.height, _sampleView.frame.size.width, _sampleView.frame.origin.x,
       _sampleView.frame.origin.y);
```

What I am trying to do I am trying to add one more view over previously present view programmatically. I did this in following manner:

```
 UIView *subView = [[UIView alloc] init];
subView.frame = _sampleView.frame;
[self.view addSubview:subView];
```

Above thing working fine on IOS7 but not on IOS8.

How to resolve this issue. Am I doing anything wrong? Need Some help. Thank you.

Comment: You have create project with XCOde 6 & later , in iOS 8 apple has introduced size class & UIView width height is 600 also it can't be changed...

Comment: then how to get correct size at run time in such case.

Comment: Second view ur adding on top of uiviewcontroller view only ... add to _sampleview addsubview:subview

Comment: try to log sizes at viewWillAppear, at viewDidLoad it has size that is specified in storyboard i guess, and correct size is applied later after it's added into view hierarchy.

Comment: But in my case I don't want to include it into my _sampleview. I want to add it into main view it self.

Comment: @wirrwarr its giving same values in viewdidload as well in viewwillappear method

Comment: that's weird, as at that point all views should have final sizes. Looks like you have some code that is changing frames/constraints after that.

Comment: Yes I have that type of code. But even though I am not executing that code still it is giving me those values. I will debug more and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

On Xcode 6 the storyboards start with a screen size of 600x600, so on **viewDidLoad**, since the views haven't yet been resized to the screen you still get that size.

If you want to know the size on screen of elements you need to look at them after they've been correctly placed and resized on screen. You can check that on **viewDidLayoutSubviews** of your view controller.

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f ", _sampleView.frame.size.height, _sampleView.frame.size.width, _sampleView.frame.origin.x, _sampleView.frame.origin.y);
}
```

You shouldn't however add any subviews in that method, as it will trigger itself again when laying out the view you just added, causing an infinite cycle. Use it only for figuring out the correct size of your views.

If you really want to add a view on that method, use a control boolean or something like that to make sure you only do it once.

If you want to add the view in a more correct way, the thing you can do is to programmatically add some autolayout constraints on this new view you're adding, to make sure it behaves like the original one.

Refer to this article for a tutorial on how to use autolayout programmatically: http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout-programmatically/

Comment: thank you for your replay. I will try your solution and let know. Is this the correct way to handle this situation?

Comment: In some cases I am getting proper value but in some some cases I am still getting 600 value inside view DidLayoutSubViews also.

Comment: That is weird, I was convinced that you would always get the resized values on that method. You can always go for the autolayout option, where you add the view and set the constraints so it behaves like the original view you already had there.